# Circumvent the limitation of 22 parametres for scala 2.10 in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am aiming to develop Spark Streaming applications which I need to use various case clsses mostly more than 22 fields..I also use kryo serializer..I wanted to know what is the best option to override this limitation..

I want to use tuples but not sue if this works when I do serializing in Spark?

Comment: This limitation has nothing to do with Spark, it's a Scala limitation that was removed in 2.11.x

Answer (score 0):

Create more case classes and compose them together instead of having one big case class:

```
case class A(b: B, c: C)
case class B(...)
case class C(...)
```

So that `A` eventually contains more than 22 fields through other case classes.

Comment: what about tuples?..case class A( a:(d:string,e:string), c:String)

Comment: @user2021147 Just nest the classes, overly bloated 30 field classes are a huge code smell.

Comment: That works with tuple too. But you might want to use case class instead as they usually offer a clearer representation of the system thanks to variable names and an easier manipulation mechanisms.

Comment: Somehow, I prefer tuples, I am using so many maps afterwad.. I am using a functional language.. and also I amusing so many inheritance in my codes..

Answer (score 0):

Case classes can't be serialized using the Kryo serializer, you'll have to use regular classes for that purpose like :

```
class A extends Serializable{

  var a:String = ""
  var b:String = ""
  //....
  var z:String = ""
}
```